# What is inverse function to XOR?

Tags: java, xor, inverse

There is XOR function in Java - `a^b`

For exemple: `5^3 = 6`

Can you tell me inverse function? If I have `6` and `3` can i get range of numbers which include number `5`?

Answer (score 340, accepted):

The inverse is XOR!

If you have:

```
c = a^b;
```

You can get `a` or `b` back if you have the other value available:

```
a = c^b; // or b^c (order is not important)
b = c^a; // or a^c
```

For example if `a = 5`, `b = 3` (and thus `c = 6` as you mentioned) you get:

```
b=0011 (3)            a=0101 (5)
c=0110 (6) XOR   or   c=0110 (6) XOR
----------            ----------
a=0101 (5)            b=0011 (3)
```

Answer (score 26):

The inverse of XOR is XOR itself. 
I came across a similar problem on leetcode. [Leetcode-1720](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-xored-array/)

Comment: Just like you, the leetcode a programming Treasure

Answer (score 14):

The inverse of XOR is XOR itself. For example if you take this operation :

```
3 ^ 4 = 7
```

The following statements are true :

```
4 ^ 7 = 3

3 ^ 7 = 4
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Inverse of a XOR is XOR itself.

For better reference and understanding u can refer to [LeetCode 2433](https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-314/problems/find-the-original-array-of-prefix-xor/).