# OR operation can't calculate original value?

Tags: c, byte

```
a|b=c
```

knowing `a` and `c`, how to calculate `b`

For example:

```
0011 | b = 0111
```

Knowing `a = 0011` and `c = 0111`, how to figure out `b` to be `0101`

Comment: Your problem is under-determined. It can exist several values... The most trivial answer is if a|b=c for b unknown then b=c is a valid answer...

Comment: could you please clarify your question.

Comment: You are confusing or `|` and xor `^`, or is under-determined. However, with xor the solution would be [What is inverse function to XOR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279866/what-is-inverse-function-to-xor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be more than one correct answer.

For simplicity consider the trivial example: `1|0 = 1` i.e. a=1, b=0 and c=1. In this case, b can also be 1.

So given that the bit in `a` is 1, we won't be able to know for sure whether the bit in `b` is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

In some logics there is also a "value" for unknown `X`

So if you want to get `b`from `a|b=c` => `0011 | b = 0111` the in my mind nicest answer would be `01XX`

Everything that is:

- `0` in `c` has to be `0` in `b`
- `1` in `c` and `0` in `a` has to be `1` in `b`
- `1` in `c` and `1` in `a` is unknown `X`