# Inequality with XOR

Tags: xor

[Given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14279946/11357458) that inverse of XOR is a XOR.

Considering only non-negative integers.
Given 3 integers, `a`, `low` and `high`. We want to find all integers, `b`, such that:

> low <= a^b <= high

Let low=2, high=6, a=1, b is variable.

> 2 <= 1^b <= 6

Since XOR is inverse of XOR, doing `1^` on each side inequality:

> 1^2 <= 1^1^b <= 1^6

which simplifies to

> 3 <= b <= 7

This is incorrect.

1. According to this minimum value of `b` for which `2 <= 1^b <= 6` is 3 but minimum value is 2.
2. b can take value of 6 but `1^6 = 7` which does not fall in range of `2 to 6`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that XOR is not monotone, e.g., `3<5` but `3^4 > 5^4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong in assuming that XOR is monotonic, and that these two equations below are equal:

> 2 <= 1^b <= 6 ............... 1^2 <= 1^1^b <= 1^6

This propery is not true at all, by xoring different numbers you might change the order. XOR 1 means simply that you toggle bit 1, so 2 will become 3, but 3 will become 2.

Comment: Is there a name of this property which is inapplicable for XOR but works for (+,-) and (/,*) ?